# python assistance - syntaxerror: unexpected character after line continuation character

Tags: python

I have just started to learn python and I keep receiving the following error:
syntaxerror: unexpected character after line continuation character

```
c:\users\myname\python>python helloworld.py
```

The code works in cmd but not python. 
I'm using Python version 3.7.2

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The things that work in cmd have *absolutely no overlap* with the things that work in Python.  A command that invokes `python` is utterly meaningless from within Python.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, so do I change the line to c:\users\myname\python>helloworld.py?

Comment: From within Python, `import helloworld` would be the closest equivalent, but doesn't necessarily do the same thing.  You may need to simply exit Python and run the command from cmd.  (Note that in no case would you be typing in the ` c:\users\myname\python>` part, that's just an example of the cmd prompt you'd be seeing.)

Comment: I see! Thanks for your help! Much appreciated